# bitcoind with rpcauth: how to use rpcauth with curl?

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc

In bitcoin.conf, if the rpcuser/rpcpassword is specified, I can access the RPC via curl like this:

```
curl --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id": "test", "method": "getblockchaininfo", "params": []}'  http://user:pass@127.0.0.1:8332/
```

Now that the rpcuser/rpcpassword option has been deprecated in favor of the new rpcauth option:

```
rpcauth=user:3f7c53e8c31facfaabbccf7bc4c02775$4f81f1a9c46a366d55bdf2f94ad7ddeeaa8d37cab0942430f2beffc7aca5d916
```

How can the rpcauth string be used to authenticate curl access?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, that's the point.

The rpcauth string is generated by the rpcauth tool, and contains a hash of your password. You authenticate exactly the same way: by providing the username and password. But you can't go back from rpcauth string to password.

Comment: BTW, in Bitcoin Core v25, there is bitcoin.conf file attached that contains commented out all options, among them there are
# Password for JSON-RPC connections
#rpcpassword=<pw>
(...)
# Username for JSON-RPC connections
#rpcuser=<user>

Why are those there if they are deprecated?